# Javascript function not executing despite satisfying "if/else"

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

First of all, I would like to apologize since the following code has been written in Danish and might not make any sense to non-danish people.

I've written this piece of code:
 [JSFiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.net/MonkeyInMyPants/Lshgrrvu/)

I have a function that asks the user how many years the user wants to analyze:

```
function udregnAnalyseAr() {
        var virksomhedsnavn = prompt("Hvad hedder den virksomhed du arbejder med?");
        var analysear;
        ar = parseFloat(prompt("Hvor mange analyseår er der?"));
        if (ar <= 1.00)     {
    analysear = "Der er ikke tilstrækkeligt antal år til at lave en sammenlignende rentabilitetsanalyse.<br>";
        }
    else if (ar > 1.00){
  analysear = "Der er blevet registreret " + ar + " regnskabsår.<br>";
        }
    else{
  analysear = "Skriv svaret som en talværdi eksempel: 2<br>";
    }
  document.getElementById("analyseArId").innerHTML = "Din virksomhed er blevet registreret som ";
  document.getElementById("analyseArId").innerHTML += virksomhedsnavn;
  document.getElementById("analyseArId").innerHTML += ".<br>";
  document.getElementById("analyseArId").innerHTML += analysear;
}
```

Later down I have another function that is supposed to write some text based on how many years the user has inputted and what value the user submitted in the second function. My issue is that my entire 3rd function doesn't execute for some reason, even when the `if (ar <= 2.00) {}` is satisfied.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If `ar`has a defined value, the third block (second `else`) will never be executed because either the first one is executed (ar<=1.00) or the second one is executed (ar>1.00)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. If ar is defined as a non-nummerical value or as NaN it will trigger the

else{
  analysear = "Skriv svaret som en talværdi eksempel: 2<br>";
    }

Comment: If it's NaN it will trigger the else but if it is a non numerical value as for example a string there might be an implicit conversion to number and trigger any of the first two blocks.